# The type initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am running an ASP Core project on my linux box.

I have done very little on the boilerplate itself, save a few models built.

I tried running the project this morning and suddenly it breaks. Nothing works. I have snooped the internet for a couple of hours now but all to avail, because most of the users experiencing this issue are running in a mac system. See the stack trace below .

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred: The type initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception.
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl': The specified module could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Interop.Crypto.GetMaxMdSize()
   at Interop.Crypto..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.Crypto.EvpMd5()
   at Internal.Cryptography.HashProviderDispenser.CreateHashProvider(String hashAlgorithmId)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Implementation..ctor()
   at Npgsql.FrontendMessages.PasswordMessage.CreateMD5(String password, String username, Byte[] serverSalt)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ProcessAuthenticationMessage(String username, AuthenticationRequestMessage msg)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.HandleAuthentication(String username, NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.Allocate(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.OpenInternal()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreated()
```

Any possible ideas or solution

Comment: Is System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl present?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth where ? where should i check for that ?

Comment: You can turn on LD_DEBUG to get the locations it probes. Also, it could be a bug that has been fixed only recently: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12517

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I cant find any useful information in LD_DEBUG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the question up for about 2 days ... got nothing.

Anyways , all i had to do was move to the NetCoreApp : 1.1.0 Version.

I installed the version and i was good :)

Thank you S.O.